# How to determine the order of $x$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there general method to solve the following problem:

Take an algebra $A$ over a field of characteristic $p$. It is knows that an element $x\in A$ is a root of a particular polynomial $q\in A[X]$. What is the order of $x$?

Comment: $x$ is a root of $X-x \in A[X]$, but certainly this is not what you're looking for. What do you mean by "order of $x$"?

Comment: Do you mean the order of vanishing of the polynomial at one of its root ?